# What do I do to resolve these installation errors with Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 2

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-7-x64, failed-installation, vs-community-edition

I have windows 7 pro x64 installed with .net f/w 4.5.2.

I had VS Community 2015 installed and it used to work fine. On installing the update 2 for community I get the following errors.

[image: VS Community 2015 error]

Now I cannot even start VS Community 2015. :-(

I've the scoured the internet and other posts on stack overflow but cannot get any help. What should I do?

Thanks for your time

Update

I ran the installer a second time and this time it installed without any errors (thus I do not have anything to show here). However I still cannot launch VS Community (just silently crashes after displaying the splash screen for about 10 seconds)...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Delete Update files from Program Files and try to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Open an administrative CMD window and navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE and run these commands as below, then open VS.

devenv /resetuserdata

devenv /resetsettings